# Crear formato especifico de json desde .Net C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Trabajo en una aplicacion ASP MVC, tengo la necesidad de armar una cadena Json como esta:

```
{
    "columns": [
        [ "Name" ],
        [ "Position" ],
        [ "Office" ],
        [ "Extn." ],
        [ "Start date" ],
        [ "Salary" ]
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            "Tiger Nixon",
            "System Architect",
            "Edinburgh",
            "5421",
            "2011/04/25",
            "$320,800"
        ],
        [
            "Garrett Winters",
            "Accountant",
            "Tokyo",
            "8422",
            "2011/07/25",
            "$170,750"
        ],
        [
            "Ashton Cox",
            "Junior Technical Author",
            "San Francisco",
            "1562",
            "2009/01/12",
            "$86,000"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Esta cadena deberá se estar armada a partir del nombre de las columnas y el contenido de las celdas de cada row del DataTable, actualmente uso esta lógica para construir la cadena:

```
    public string DataTableToJSONWithStringBuilder(DataTable table)
    {
        var jsonString = new StringBuilder();
        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            jsonString.Append("{\"columns\": ");
            for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                jsonString.Append("[\"" + table.Columns[j].ColumnName + "\"],");
            }

            jsonString.Append("\"data\": [");
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    jsonString.Append("[");
                else
                    jsonString.Append(",[");
                for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
                {

                    if (j == 1)
                    {
                        jsonString.Append("\"" + table.Rows[i][j] + "\"");
                    } else if (j < table.Columns.Count - 1 && j > 1)
                    {
                        jsonString.Append(", \"" + table.Rows[i][j] + "\"");
                    }
                    else if (j == table.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        jsonString.Append(", \"" + table.Rows[i][j] + "\"]");
                    }
                }

            }
            jsonString.Append("]}");
        }
        return jsonString.ToString();
    }
```

Esta función me crea una cadena como esta:

> {{"**columns**": ["Descripcion"],["Unidad"],["Cantidad"],["MAT MOVIL
>   SA DE C.V"],["MATERIALES INDUSTRIALES JEREZ S. DE R.L. DE
>   C.V."],["GAMA MATERIALES Y ACEROS, SA DE CV"],["FERRETERA INDUSTRIAL
>   ROMA, S.A. DE C.V"],["REQUISICION DE MATERIAL"],["COMERCIAL TDK DE
>   MONTERREY, S.A. DE C.V."],["Comercializadora Branco SA DE
>   CV"],["Harmak Materiales SA DE CV "],["ACEROMEX S.A. DE
>   C.V."],["LIMPIEZA DE SISTEMA"],["LOWES COMPANIES MEXICO S. DE R.L DE
>   C.V"],["JESUS GARZA DE LA CRUZ"],["ENEDINA RIOS
>   TREVIÑO"],["ABASTECEDORA DE VIVIENDA Y ARQUITECTOS DM, S.A. DE
>   C.V."],["Materiales Para La Construccion DPI S.A.P.I de
>   C.V."],["Ferreteria Indumex SA de CV"],["ACEROS Y DERIVADOS SA DE CV
>   "],["Viveros y Pastos Allende S de RL de CV"],"**data**": [["KG",
>   "46", "Unidad: $26.00   Total: $1,387.36", "Unidad: $0.00   Total:
>   $0.00", "Unidad: $17.07   Total: $910.86", "Unidad: $20.60   Total:
>   $1,099.22", "Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00", "Unidad: $26.00   Total:
>   $1,387.36", "Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00", "Unidad: $0.00   Total:
>   $0.00", "Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00", "Unidad: $0.00   Total:
>   $0.00", "Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00", "Unidad: $25.00   Total:
>   $1,334.00", "Unidad: $21.55   Total: $1,149.91", "Unidad: $18.00
>   Total: $960.48", "Unidad: $24.20   Total: $1,291.31", "Unidad: $27.30 
>   Total: $1,456.73", "Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00", "n/a"],["KG", "90",
>   "n/a", "Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00", "Unidad: $32.92   Total:
>   $3,436.85", "Unidad: $33.22   Total: $3,468.17", "Unidad: $0.00
>   Total: $0.00", "Unidad: $40.00   Total: $4,176.00", "Unidad: $0.00
>   Total: $0.00", "Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00", "Unidad: $0.00   Total:
>   $0.00", "Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00", "Unidad: $0.00   Total:
>   $0.00", "Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00", "Unidad: $43.10   Total:
>   $4,499.64", "Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00", "Unidad: $0.00   Total:
>   $0.00", "Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00", "Unidad: $0.00   Total:
>   $0.00", "Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00"],["", "", "$1,196.00", "$0.00",
>   "$3,748.02", "$3,937.40", "$0.00", "$4,796.00", "$0.00", "$0.00",
>   "$0.00", "$0.00", "$0.00", "$1,150.00", "$4,870.30", "$828.00",
>   "$1,113.20", "$1,255.80", "$0.00", "$0.00"],["", "", "$191.36",
>   "$0.00", "$599.68", "$629.98", "$0.00", "$767.36", "$0.00", "$0.00",
>   "$0.00", "$0.00", "$0.00", "$184.00", "$779.25", "$132.48", "$178.11",
>   "$200.93", "$0.00", "$0.00"],["", "", "$1,387.36", "$0.00",
>   "$4,347.70", "$4,567.38", "$0.00", "$5,563.36", "$0.00", "$0.00",
>   "$0.00", "$0.00", "$0.00", "$1,334.00", "$5,649.55", "$960.48",
>   "$1,291.31", "$1,456.73", "$0.00", "$0.00"]]}}

Pero a mi vista me llega esto:

> {   "xx": "{\"columns\":
>   [\"Descripcion\"],[\"Unidad\"],[\"Cantidad\"],[\"MAT MOVIL SA DE
>   C.V\"],[\"MATERIALES INDUSTRIALES JEREZ S. DE R.L. DE C.V.\"],[\"GAMA
>   MATERIALES Y ACEROS, SA DE CV\"],[\"FERRETERA INDUSTRIAL ROMA, S.A. DE
>   C.V\"],[\"REQUISICION DE MATERIAL\"],[\"COMERCIAL TDK DE MONTERREY,
>   S.A. DE C.V.\"],[\"Comercializadora Branco SA DE CV\"],[\"Harmak
>   Materiales SA DE CV \"],[\"ACEROMEX S.A. DE C.V.\"],[\"LIMPIEZA DE
>   SISTEMA\"],[\"LOWES COMPANIES MEXICO S. DE R.L DE C.V\"],[\"JESUS
>   GARZA DE LA CRUZ\"],[\"ENEDINA RIOS TREVIÑO\"],[\"ABASTECEDORA DE
>   VIVIENDA Y ARQUITECTOS DM, S.A. DE C.V.\"],[\"Materiales Para La
>   Construccion DPI S.A.P.I de C.V.\"],[\"Ferreteria Indumex SA de
>   CV\"],[\"ACEROS Y DERIVADOS SA DE CV \"],[\"Viveros y Pastos Allende S
>   de RL de CV\"],\"data\": [[\"KG\", \"46\", \"Unidad: $26.00   Total:
>   $1,387.36\", \"Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00\", \"Unidad: $17.07
>   Total: $910.86\", \"Unidad: $20.60   Total: $1,099.22\", \"Unidad:
>   $0.00   Total: $0.00\", \"Unidad: $26.00   Total: $1,387.36\",
>   \"Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00\", \"Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00\",
>   \"Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00\", \"Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00\",
>   \"Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00\", \"Unidad: $25.00   Total:
>   $1,334.00\", \"Unidad: $21.55   Total: $1,149.91\", \"Unidad: $18.00
>   Total: $960.48\", \"Unidad: $24.20   Total: $1,291.31\", \"Unidad:
>   $27.30   Total: $1,456.73\", \"Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00\",
>   \"n/a\"],[\"KG\", \"90\", \"n/a\", \"Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00\",
>   \"Unidad: $32.92   Total: $3,436.85\", \"Unidad: $33.22   Total:
>   $3,468.17\", \"Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00\", \"Unidad: $40.00
>   Total: $4,176.00\", \"Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00\", \"Unidad: $0.00 
>   Total: $0.00\", \"Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00\", \"Unidad: $0.00
>   Total: $0.00\", \"Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00\", \"Unidad: $0.00
>   Total: $0.00\", \"Unidad: $43.10   Total: $4,499.64\", \"Unidad: $0.00
>   Total: $0.00\", \"Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00\", \"Unidad: $0.00
>   Total: $0.00\", \"Unidad: $0.00   Total: $0.00\", \"Unidad: $0.00
>   Total: $0.00\"],[\"\", \"\", \"$1,196.00\", \"$0.00\", \"$3,748.02\",
>   \"$3,937.40\", \"$0.00\", \"$4,796.00\", \"$0.00\", \"$0.00\",
>   \"$0.00\", \"$0.00\", \"$0.00\", \"$1,150.00\", \"$4,870.30\",
>   \"$828.00\", \"$1,113.20\", \"$1,255.80\", \"$0.00\",
>   \"$0.00\"],[\"\", \"\", \"$191.36\", \"$0.00\", \"$599.68\",
>   \"$629.98\", \"$0.00\", \"$767.36\", \"$0.00\", \"$0.00\", \"$0.00\",
>   \"$0.00\", \"$0.00\", \"$184.00\", \"$779.25\", \"$132.48\",
>   \"$178.11\", \"$200.93\", \"$0.00\", \"$0.00\"],[\"\", \"\",
>   \"$1,387.36\", \"$0.00\", \"$4,347.70\", \"$4,567.38\", \"$0.00\",
>   \"$5,563.36\", \"$0.00\", \"$0.00\", \"$0.00\", \"$0.00\", \"$0.00\",
>   \"$1,334.00\", \"$5,649.55\", \"$960.48\", \"$1,291.31\",
>   \"$1,456.73\", \"$0.00\", \"$0.00\"]]}" }

Para mandar a llamar al controller que devuelve esa cadena json uso este fragmento de ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/controller/actionjson',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'params': parametros }),
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (xx) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(xx, null, 2));
    }
});
```

¿Que necesito ajustar para obtener la estructura json que deseo?

Comment: Aunque no esta exactamente relacionado con tu pregunta,yo te recomendaría usar [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) para cualquier tipo de operaciones que usen Json (Serializar/deserializar). Te ahorrara mucho trabajo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás trabajando con base en un DataTable, tienes que obtener primero las columnas y después recorrer cada renglón para obtener los datos, para finalmente serializar tu objeto (como te menciona Pikoh, con `using Newtonsoft.Json`):

```
List<string> _c = new List<string>();     // Aquí almacenas las columnas
List<object[]> _d = new List<object[]>(); // y aquí los datos.
DataTable dt = ... // Como sea que obtengas tus datos

foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    _c.Add(dc.ColumnName);  // Creas el arreglo de las columnas (solo los nombres)
}

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    object[] _obj = new object[_c.Count];
    for(int x = 0; x < _c.Count; x++)
    {
        _obj[x] = dr[x].ToString(); // Añades a un arreglo "interno" cada dato en el renglón.
    }
    _d.Add(_obj); // Añades al arreglo "final" el arreglo interno.
}
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { columns = _c, data = _d });
```

*EDIT*

Ya veo lo de los nombres de las columnas, para ello solo hay que modificar estas dos líneas:

```
List<string[]> _c = new List<string[]>();     // Aquí almacenas las columnas
```

y

```
_c.Add(new string[1] { dc.ColumnName });  // Creas el arreglo de las columnas (solo los nombres)
```

Dan Miranda menciona que hay que declarar `_c` como `List<List<string>>`, que también funciona con `_c.Add(new List<string>(){ dc.ColumnName })`.

Comment: Hola Kroneaux: El detalle es que necesito el formato que menciono en mi pregunta para poder con eso crear Thead de un DataTable de Jquery.

Comment: Hola @joseluisgarcia, te comparto el resultado de hacer esto en mi propio caso, del cual no puedo compartirte más ya que es información delicada: `{"columns":["PROYECTO","NOMBRE PROYECTO"],"data":[["0000000","Atotonilco PTAR"],...]}`. Según yo, es el formato que estás pidiendo, ¿por lo menos probaste ya el código?

Comment: @Kroneaux Schneider Las columnas (_c) hay que modificarlas para que sean List<List<string>> y con eso serializan al formato deseado.

Comment: Una disculpa Luis, ya me percaté del error en mi respuesta y la edité, aprovechando también la observación de @DanMiranda.

Comment: Hola @KroneauxSchneider: Claro que probé el código, probare estos cambios que anexaste al mismo y regreso con mis comentarios, lo que busco lograr es lo que se menciona en este link: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4764/how-to-plot-header-dynamically-by-jquery-in-datatables que es llenar un DataTable de Jquery con fuentes de datos dinamicos, en mi caso tengo informacion cargada en un DataTable de .Net que deseo cargar al DataTable de Jquery solon que como las columnas son dinamicas me tope con este inconveniente. Gracias pruebo tus sugerencias y regreso con mis comentarios.

Comment: KroneauxSchneider muchas gracias, me funciono tu fragmento de código con los ajustes que comento @Dan Miranda, solo tuve que cambiar esta linea: **return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { columns = _c, data = _d });** por esta otra **return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { columns = c, data = d }));**

Comment: Me alegro que te funcionara, y de hecho lo hace tanto con lo que menciona Dan como con las ediciones que te mencioné por mi cuenta; lo que yo te sugería consume menos memoria. Y recuerda que hay más de una forma de llegar al resultado, he ahí un claro ejemplo.